# .NET: Method to Insert String into Beginning of Each Item in a Collection?

Tags: c#, string, vb.net, replace, collections

Let's say I have a `SortedList` collection of strings (though any collection type should be the same, generally), and they're all file names...

Now, I want to append (`insert` at position 0) the same full file path to each item in that collection.

Rather than doing a `For Each` Loop, something like:

```
For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In mySortedList
  entry.Value = entry.Value.Insert(0, "C:\some\path\")
Next
```

I'm wondering if there's a one-line method to do this? Kinda along the lines of:

```
' Pseudo code (I know its wrong, just demonstrating the idea)

mySortedList = mySortedList.Items.Insert(0, "C:\some\path\")
```

Then I'd have a new sorted list with the full path to the file as each item.

It's been awhile since I've coded in PHP but going on memory I think `Array_Walk()` did something like what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I would assume that if there was such a class that this class would just do the loop anyways

Comment: Do you actually need to modify the existing collection, or would creating a new `SortedList` work for you? Or can you just do this on the fly when you're iterating over the collection? If you could provide more precise requirements it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky but you could try something like:

```
var newFilenames = mySortedList.Values.Cast<string>().Select(s => s.Insert(0, @"C:\some\path\"));
```

This worked for me but it probably doesn't have any performance benefit over just foreaching the collection.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it when I get back home. I do look for performance bennies as well as code cleanliness/readability though, but it would still be nice to add to my code repertoire. =)

Comment: Nothing “hacky” about it. That’s what LINQ is for. I’d concatenate rather than insert but I doubt there’s any performance penalty your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you use `Linq`.

`list.Select(s => "C:\some\path\" + s);`

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It does the job. list = list.Select(s => "C:\some\path\" + s);

Comment: @siggi_pop I didn't downvote it, but I will try it when I get back home.

Comment: @siggi_pop: The code in the answer *just* calls `Select` without using the result. That isn't helpful - it looks like it does the right thing, but it doesn't do anything. Note that depending on the type of `list`, your small change wouldn't work either - if `list` is of type `List<T>`, it won't compile. Next there's the fact that the OP has a `SortedList`, which wouldn't implement `IEnumerable<string>` anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi John Skeet - an honour. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The VB solution:

```
Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"path one", "Path two", "Path three"}

list = list.Select(Function(s) s.Insert(0, "C:\some\path\")).ToList()
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have a `List<T>` though. They have a `SortedList<string, string>` by the looks of it... and it sounds like they want to *modify* the existing collection rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @JonSkeet Nice, thanks. I'll pay more attention to types in the future. Out of curiosity, does it matter much that the list is reassigned? doesn't the initial list object get garbage collected anyway?

Comment: It could make a huge difference - because there may be a reference to the collection elsewhere. Sometimes what you want is to modify the existing collection so that the other code can see the changes - other times you want a new collection specifically so that the other code *doesn't* see the changes.